# Can't drag stored procedure onto dbml designer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do a simple call to a database stored procedure from a C# application.

I'm following a guide like, e.g., [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918119.aspx) or [this one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx)

Both of these have the same basic steps.

1. Add a LINQ to SQL .dbml item to my project
2. Connect to a database in Server Explorer
3. Drag a stored procedure from the Server Explorer onto my .dbml designer window

But step 3 doesn't work. I have my stored procedure and my designer window, but I can't drag the sproc. I don't get a plus sign, or a "not allowed" sign. It's just a non-dragable object.

I can't find another way to add my sproc to the .dbml file. And I can't find anyone else who has had this problem. Every source simply says to drag it over.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Andomar I've posted what I can see. I don't know how to capture the cursor. PrintScreen doesn't seem to capture it, and I don't think I can do it with Snipping Tool. Regardless, it wouldn't really show anything since I can't actually drag the sproc anywhere. It just looks like my cursor is hovering over the .dbml window, but in reality I'm clicking and dragging.

Comment: That's exactly how my screen looks.  For me it works even if the DBML file is readonly.  Are you logged in locally?  Are both you and VS running under the same administrator account?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in locally and VS is running under the same account. I'm also connected to the remote SQL server using the same Windows credentials.

Comment: Did you try a reboot?  Disable the virus scanner?  Is there another application active that interacts with the clipboard?

Comment: @Andomar I figured out the problem. I had the wrong version of a dll. I've posted the solution as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out the solution was that I had the wrong version of a .dll for Visual Studio.

I noticed I was getting exceptions when performing actions in the Server Explorer. Googling the exceptions led to [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc) which points to this dll

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll
```

as the issue.

I replaced it with the corresponding copy from one of my teammates and it now works fine.

Comment: For me, it was file version 11.0.50214.1 from Microsoft Visual Studio Beta 11.  I uninstalled it, but it didn't revert this file.  Replacing it with version 10.0.30319.1 from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (I have SP1, not sure if this is the same as without SP1) worked.

Comment: @casperOne For me as well. I should have used a image for the beta, but I trusted that the uninstall would be clean. There's actually quite a bit of stuff in the Microsoft Shared directory that should have been reverted back and wasn't after the Visual Studio 11 uninstall.

Comment: Isn't that always our downfall?  We should have made an image for *beta* software and we don't? =)

Comment: Thanks, replacing 11.0.50214.1 of the dsref80.dll with a 10.0.30319.1 version fixed the same problem for me as well

Comment: This happened to me after I installed VSE for Desktop after VSE for Web.  I don't know if that was the cause, but deleting the file and repairing solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had also installed VS 11 Beta and the designer was working fine until I uninstalled it. I had to delete the DLL manually at the above location and repair the installation by finding Visual Studio 2010 in Programs and Features and selecting Uninstall/Change and then Repair. The installer will replace the DLL file that was deleted with the correct version.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that **can** drag the sproc, but sees no result (the sproc simply does not show up in the functions pane): make sure that the sproc only returns datatypes that L2S understands. For example you can not return a `geography` field.

Comment: my sp does not returns anything, instead it won't show up in the functions pane...

Comment: In my case I declared a Table type. L2S doesn't like that either. Looks like I'll have to pass a delimited string instead.

Answer (score 1):

Editing .dbml files with a designer surface requires the LINQ to SQL tools which are not installed by default as part of any of the workloads of Visual Studio 2017. It can be installed by selecting the "LINQ to SQL tools" item under the "Code Tools" category in the "Individual Components" tab of the Visual Studio installer.