# Can't drag MySQL stored procedure onto dbml(Linq)

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, stored-procedures, dbml

I want to use stored procedure of MySQL in my c# application. I have created a dbml file and connected successfully to MySQL database. I tried to select (drag and drop) the stored procedure but it is not getting done.However, I can drag and drop stored procedures of MSSQL(SQL sever). I am using Visual studio 2008. Any help would be highly regarded.

P.S - I have got few probable solutions while browsing. But, they didn't provide me the desired solution.

Thank you

Comment: What all solutions did you tried so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385307/cant-drag-stored-procedure-onto-dbml-designer