# I can't drag stored procedure from server explorer to dbml in my project - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community and doing a C# project involving SQL Server 2014. I am unable to drag my stored procedures from server explorer to the `.dbml`. It shows something like this (/) whenever I attempt to drag and drop anything. I need some help please.

This is my project below, I'm unable to drag stored procedure from the right side to the left:

[image]

Comment: Open your dbml file and try to drop into dbml file

Comment: The mouse turns into a (/) icon whenever I try to drag and drop

Comment: Try to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385307/cant-drag-stored-procedure-onto-dbml-designer

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem was that I was using visual studio premium 2013 before and the dsref80.dll file wasn't removed before i installed visual studio 2015 community. It works now after removing the file and doing a repair