# VS 2022 Enterprise ASP.NET webforms error in DataClasses1.dbml

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm getting an error where my `DataClasses1.dbml` sometimes can't drag stored procedures in it and its generating new connection string.

I tried uninstalling it and installed the community but still gets the error. So for now, I am using VS2019 which I already used before and stable.

Comment: Did this post help you? [Can't drag stored procedure onto dbml designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385307/cant-drag-stored-procedure-onto-dbml-designer)